# Roslyn Refactor Find References to a method

Tags: c#, roslyn

As part of a refactor project I am working on I need to replace calls to Obsolete methods with correct calls.  This has worked for other calls but I have hit a problem with my current one.

I need to replace all calls to the following:

```
[Obsolete("use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace instead of this extension")]
public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this string s)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s);
}
```

with the simple `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string here)` from the framework.  When run it did work in that it fixed all the instances that it found.  What I can't account for is the 200+ instances that it did not identify.

Here are two examples that it did not find, this one is from the same class.

```
public static string TrimToUpper(this string s)
{
    return !IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? s.Trim().ToUpperInvariant() : s;
}
```

I thought perhaps because the method was called directly, but that doesn't make sense to me as far as finding the reference.  A second example is simple if in another class in a project in the same solution `if (enterpriseCode.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())` The first past detected several other instances just like it but not this one.

Here is the code I am using to find all the references to the method I wish to replace:

```
public sealed class ReferenceFinder
{  
    public ReferenceFinder(string solutionPath)
    {
        SolutionInfo = GetSolutionInfo(solutionPath).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    } 
    public ReferenceTree RetreiveSolutionReferences(string typeName, string methodName)
        => new ReferenceTree(typeName, methodName, GetReferenceLocationsByProject(GetReferenceSymbols(GetTypeSymbols(typeName), methodName)));
    private IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> GetTypeSymbols(string typeName)
        => SolutionInfo.ProjectInfo.Select(pi => pi.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(typeName)).Where(x => x != null);
    private IEnumerable<ReferencedSymbol> FindConstructorReferences(INamedTypeSymbol symbol)
        => symbol.Constructors.SelectMany(c => SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(c, SolutionInfo.Solution).Result);
    private IEnumerable<ReferencedSymbol> FindMethodReferences(INamedTypeSymbol symbol, string methodName)
        => symbol.GetMembers(methodName).SelectMany(m => SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(m, SolutionInfo.Solution).Result);
    private IEnumerable<ReferencedSymbol> GetReferenceSymbols(IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> symbols, string methodName)
        => symbols.SelectMany(x => x.Name == methodName ? FindConstructorReferences(x) : FindMethodReferences(x, methodName));
    private ILookup<Project, ReferenceLocation> GetReferenceLocationsByProject(IEnumerable<ReferencedSymbol> symbols)
        => symbols.SelectMany(x => x.Locations).Distinct().ToLookup(x => x.Document.Project);
    private async Task<SolutionInfo> GetSolutionInfo(string path)
    {
        using (var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create())
        {
            var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(path);
            var compilations = await Task.WhenAll(solution.Projects.Select(async x => (x, await x.GetCompilationAsync())).AsEnumerable());
            return new SolutionInfo((solution, compilations));
        }
    }

    public readonly SolutionInfo SolutionInfo;
}
```

I am passing the RetreiveSolutionReferencs the following "DVWorkshop.StringExtensions" (the class and namespace of the method to replace) "IsNullOrWhiteSpace" (the method to replace).

I even wrote a short method to try step through and see what references were being picked up.

```
        public void GetReferencesForSpecificProject(string typeName, string methodName, string projectName)
    {
        var pi = SolutionInfo.ProjectInfo.First(x => x.Project.Name == projectName);
        var symbol = pi.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(typeName);

        var members = symbol.GetMembers(methodName).ToList();
        var rList = new List<IEnumerable<ReferenceLocation>>();
        var cList = new List<IEnumerable<Location>>();
        foreach (var m in members)
        {
            var referenceLocations = SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(m, SolutionInfo.Solution).Result.SelectMany(r => r.Locations);
            var callerLocations = SymbolFinder.FindCallersAsync(m, SolutionInfo.Solution).Result.SelectMany(r => r.Locations);

            rList.Add(referenceLocations);
            cList.Add(callerLocations);
        }
    }
```

I see several locations in the reference and callers collections, but not nearly enough and none of them are for the project I'm passing in "Application" even though I see the calls and go to definition takes me to my method.

What is causing me to miss references to my method?

Comment: Why don't try a find-and-replace approach, using regex if needed?

Comment: Also, I wonder who on this planet earth wrote such an extension in the first place!

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ tell me about it.  Unfortunately the code base was full of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When searching an assembly for a type declared in another assembly you need to get symbols from the referencing library for that method.  So for instance:

In the case that assembly A has a method called DoStuff() off of MyClass and assembly B has a method that creates an instance of MyClass and calls DoStuff().

You want to get the Symbols from Assembly A and use that to find all the references to DoStuff().  When you go to look for DoStuff() in Assembly B, you will need to get the Symbol reference from Assembly B to that same method and then search Assembly B for references to that symbol.

```
public sealed class ReferenceFinder
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<ReferenceLocation, object> processedReferenceLocations = new ConcurrentDictionary<ReferenceLocation, object>();
    public ReferenceFinder(string solutionPath) =>
        Solution = SetSolutionInfo(solutionPath).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    public ReferenceTree GetReferenceTree(string path, string typeName, string methodName) =>
        new ReferenceTree(methodName, path, GetNodeFromSymbol(typeName), GetReferenceNodes(GetReferenceSymbols(GetTypeSymbols(typeName), methodName)).SelectMany(x => GetSymbolBySyntaxType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>(x).Concat(GetSymbolBySyntaxType<ConstructorDeclarationSyntax>(x))).ToList());
    private SyntaxNode GetNodeFromSymbol(string typeName) =>
        (GetTypeSymbols(typeName).FirstOrDefault() != null) ? (GetTypeSymbols(typeName).First() as ISymbol).DeclaringSyntaxReferences.First()?.SyntaxTree.GetRoot() : null;
    private IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> GetTypeSymbols(string typeName) =>
        Compilations.Values.Select(comp => comp.GetTypeByMetadataName(typeName))                                                    //Get NamedTypeSymbols from each project
        .Where(nts => nts != null);                                                                                                 //Where the symbol isn't null
    private IEnumerable<ReferencedSymbol> GetReferenceSymbols(IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> symbols, string methodName) =>
        symbols.Concat(symbols.SelectMany(s => s.GetMembers(methodName)))                                                           //Concat the symbol with its member symbols
        .SelectMany(s => SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(s, Solution).Result);                                                     //Get the ReferencedSymbols for each NamedTypeSymbol  
    private IEnumerable<(ReferenceLocation, IEnumerable<SyntaxNode>)> GetReferenceNodes(IEnumerable<ReferencedSymbol> symbols)
       => symbols.SelectMany(refSymbol => refSymbol.Locations                                                                       //Get Locations for all the Symbols               
           .Where(refLocation => processedReferenceLocations.TryAdd(refLocation, null))).AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)   //That have not been processed before                                                                             
          .Select(rl => (rl, rl.Location.SourceTree.GetRoot().FindToken(rl.Location.SourceSpan.Start).Parent.AncestorsAndSelf()));  //Return Location and all referencing nodes         
    
    // This returns all of the reference information for a particular node type (Method or Constructor)
    private IEnumerable<(ISymbol symbol, SyntaxNode node, ReferenceLocation location, string method)> GetSymbolBySyntaxType<T>((ReferenceLocation Location, IEnumerable<SyntaxNode> Nodes) locationAndNodes) where T : SyntaxNode
    {
        var referencesOfType = locationAndNodes.Nodes.OfType<T>();
        var symbol = referencesOfType.Any() ? Compilations[locationAndNodes.Location.Document.Project.Name].GetSemanticModel(locationAndNodes.Location.Location.SourceTree.GetRoot().SyntaxTree).GetDeclaredSymbol(referencesOfType.First()) : null;

        foreach (var reference in referencesOfType)
        {
            // Both MethodDeclarationSyntax and ConstructorDeclarationSyntax have an Identifier Property that is needed.  The property however is class level and not
            // shared by the inheritance implementations, thus they must be tested individually instead of referred to as a base type.
            var method = (reference is MethodDeclarationSyntax) ? (reference as MethodDeclarationSyntax).Identifier.ValueText : (reference as ConstructorDeclarationSyntax).Identifier.ValueText;
            yield return (symbol, reference, locationAndNodes.Location, method);
        }
    }
    private async Task<Solution> SetSolutionInfo(string path)
    {
        using (var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create())
        {
            var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(path);
            var compilations = await Task.WhenAll(solution.Projects.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(10).Select(async x => (x, await x.GetCompilationAsync())).AsEnumerable());
            Compilations = compilations.ToDictionary(x => x.x.Name, x => x.Item2);
            return solution;
        }
    }
    private Solution Solution;
    private Dictionary<string, Compilation> Compilations = new Dictionary<string, Compilation>();
}
```

Then in your calling class:

```
    private static IEnumerable<ReferenceTree> FindReferences(ReferenceFinder finder, ReferenceTree woods)
    {
        // Yield the Method Reference itself
        yield return woods;

        // For each reference to this reference
        foreach (var tree in woods.References.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(10).Select(x =>
                                                    finder.GetReferenceTree(x.Location.Document.FilePath,
                                                    x.Symbol.GetQualifiedClassName(),
                                                    x.Node is MethodDeclarationSyntax ? (x.Node as MethodDeclarationSyntax).Identifier.ValueText :
                                                    (x.Node as ConstructorDeclarationSyntax).Identifier.ValueText))
                                                .Distinct())
        {
            // Yield the immediate child references
            yield return tree;

            // Recursively get and yield all referencing methods  
            foreach (var branch in tree.References.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)
                                .SelectMany(x => FindReferences(
                                        finder,
                                        finder.GetReferenceTree(
                                                x.Location.Document.FilePath,
                                                x.Symbol.GetQualifiedClassName(),
                                                x.Node is MethodDeclarationSyntax ? (x.Node as MethodDeclarationSyntax).Identifier.ValueText :
                                                (x.Node as ConstructorDeclarationSyntax).Identifier.ValueText))))
            {
                yield return branch;
            }
        }
    }
```